# Cannot Create Python Virtual Environment on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.7

Whenever I run `python3 -m venv venv` I get this error. I don't get this error on my Mac that is the version behind Mojave. I'm not sure what the issue is, and the error text is very brief:

`Error: Command /Users/marcus/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.`

Operating System: Mac OS 10.14.3

Python Version: 3.7.2

Blood Pressure: high

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realized after staring at the line for so long that it was complaining mostly about pip and that this was probably caused by Mac OS X's system pip, which is protected.

My venv came alive with the without pip flags like so: `python3 -m venv venv --without-pip`.

here's what works for me the best:

`virtualenv -p python3 venv && source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: This actually made my nightmare worse because then I cannot use pip in the venv

Comment: Might be helpful for others:-- you can install pip after activating the venv. I faced similar issue, creating venv without pip, and then installing pip worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs in to this issue on Mac OS, if your .venv folder is already there (as was mine), deleting it and re-running the python3 -m venv .venv command worked for me.